# Fragment toolbar back button is not showing after i launched the app in play store

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

This is my first app release in google play. I am using MVVM architecture in this project. I am using NAVIGATION of android JETPACK. So, I have one activity and rest others are fragments. When i am running my app with android studio its showing the back button in toolbar, but when i download my app from play store its not showing back button. Its working like back button but back button icon is not there. I dont have any clue why its happening.

Here is the codes used 
Activity

```
class SchoolDiaryMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_diary_main)


    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val host: NavHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

    val navController = host.navController

    setupActionBar(navController)
    setupNavigationMenu(navController)
}

private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController) {
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
}

private fun setupNavigationMenu(navController: NavController) {
    findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)?.let { navigationView ->
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)

    }
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(
        drawerLayout,
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
    )
    onBackPressed()
    return true
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val retValue = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_empty, menu)
    return retValue
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(
        item,
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
    )
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

//activity_school_diary_main

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:context=".activities.SchoolDiaryMainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"/>
        <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Some part of nav_graph that i have used for connecting fragments as part of navigation rule of android jetpack

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
                app:startDestination="@+id/diaryMainFrag">

<fragment android:id="@+id/testFragmentOne" android:name="amit.diary.studentdiaryentryTwo.fragments.TestFragmentOne"
          android:label="af_test_one" tools:layout="@layout/af_test_one"/>
<fragment android:id="@+id/diaryMainFrag" android:name="amit.diary.studentdiaryentryTwo.fragments.DiaryMainFrag"
          android:label="af_diary_main" tools:layout="@layout/af_diary_main">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_diaryMainFrag_to_homeworkFrag" app:destination="@id/homeworkFrag"/>
```

Except that inside fragment there is no line of code to control toolbar. I dont think in navigation anywhere its there for backbutton i need code in my fragment.
[image: Google play app image]

[image: Android studio app image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Navigation 1.0.0-beta01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#1.0.0-beta01):

> Fixed an issue where the NavigationUI handled back arrow would not appear when using ProGuard with obfuscation. [b/123449431](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123449431)

So upgrade to the latest version - currently `1.0.0-rc02`.